# Seeking pre-1825 birth/baptism record in Prussia for George Fesch?

Tags: birth-records, 1820s, prussia

I am seeking a birth/baptism for George Fesch who was probably born prior to 1825 in Prussia, possibly in Cassel Hesse.

I have not found a marriage record for George but his son Augustus Otto was born 1845 in Cassel Hesse.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Are you able to provide a source/link for the birth of Augustus?  From that a potential answerer might be able to find his siblings' births/baptisms, his parents' marriage and other stepping stones to his own birth/baptism record.